# Jenkins/Sonar - new error after server restart

Tags: configuration, jenkins, sonarqube

Quick question about sonar/jenkins integration.

First, a little background - we're working on implementing the build pipeline plugin, and last night we had an issue where one of our pipeline jobs lost its history.  This took out all of our executors (even on the slaves).  I tried renaming and I tried bouncing and that didn't work.  Finally, I brought down the master, cleared everything from temp and work in Tomcat, and brought it back up.  This fixed the issues with my executors.

So this morning I run a build that runs Sonar as a post-build step.  Now I am seeing this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project VendorProduct: Can not execute Sonar: The current batch process and the configured remote server do not share the same DB configuration.
[ERROR] - Batch side: jdbc:oracle:thin:@dansrzl105si.wellsfargo.com:3203/LBLDFRI1 (QMTDO / *****)
[ERROR] - Server side: check the configuration at http://lpwva3279:9000/sonar/system
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project VendorProduct: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: The current batch process and the configured remote server do not share the same DB configuration.
    - Batch side: jdbc:oracle:thin:@dansrzl105si.wellsfargo.com:3203/LBLDFRI1 (QMTDO / *****)
    - Server side: check the configuration at http://lpwva3279:9000/sonar/system

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I've verified the configuration against the sonar configuration file, deleted and recreated the post-build step, deleted and recreated the sonar instance on the Jenkins configuration page.  I'm at a loss here.  Any one have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This message is printed out when a Sonar batch connects to a database which is not the same as the one configured on the Sonar Web server.

In your case, if you go to `http://lpwva3279:9000/sonar/system`, there are chances that the DB config settings that you'll find are not the same as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@dansrzl105si.wellsfargo.com:3203/LBLDFRI1 (QMTDO / *****)`. You should then go to your Jenkins settings and update the information relating to Sonar to match the one found on the Sonar Web server.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to http://host:port/sonar/system:**

Copy value "Database URL" into Jenkins configuration ("Database URL")

Copy value "Database Login" into Jenkins configuration ("Database Login")

Copy value "Database Driver" into Jenkins configuration ("Database Driver")

**And go to SONAR_HOME/conf/sonar.properties:**

Copy value "Database password" into Jenkins configuration ("Database password")